# Probability that I win more than three dollars.

Tags: probability

There are three slot machines.

The prize money in each is 1,2,3 dollars respectively;

The probability of winning in respective slot machines is 0.1, 0.4, 0.7 respectively.

What is the probability that I will win at least three dollars.?

I have to play them in the order they are given and there is no cost of playing.

Comment: You choose which to play, or you play them all, or...? The prizes are \$1, \$2, \$3 for each machine, respectively, I suppose.

Comment: I have to play them all one by one.

Comment: How much does it cost to play each machine? How much money do you have to start with?

Comment: If it costs $1$ dollar per game, does winning at least three dollars mean getting my money back from three one-dollar games, or ending up with three dollars more than I started with?

Comment: Are you limited to only play once each? Or can you play as many times as you want to?

Comment: Note that thetitle and body questions differ (and have different answers): One aske for *more than* three dollrs, th eother for *at least* three dollors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that winning in the third game, you got at least \$3. So, the outcomes you're interested in are

1. victory in the third game: $0.7$,
2. loss in the third game, but victory in the first two: $0.1 \cdot 0.4 \cdot (1-0.7)$.

Your answer is the sum of the two cases, i.e. $0.712$.

Comment: What if we generalise this for N slot machines?

Comment: And sorry I cannot upvote. Your answer is same as mine.

Comment: For $N$ machines, you need to see what outcomes you are interested in, and then compute each outcome's probability, and sum them. I made it easier above by using the fact that the victory in third means an overall victory, regardless of the other two, so I've seamlessly joined $\{(L,L,W),(W,L,W),(L,W,W),(W,W,W)\}$ into a single possibility $(*,*,W)$. But, this was a special case. Had your target been $4$, this wouldn't be possible. Instead, your events would be $\{(W,W,W), (W,L,W), (L,W,W)\}$, you'd compute these three probabilities, and sum them ($L$ = lose, $W$ = win).

Comment: @Alice you should be able to vote up now. :) (just +1'd)

Comment: @VedranŠego thanks. I was hoping I could generalise this scenario for large values of N.

Comment: Well, you can: Find all viable scenarios, compute their probability and sum that. Anything easier than that is specific to some case. For example, if each machine gives you at least $\$k$ and the probability of each victory is $p_i$, then your overall probability to win at least $\$k$ is $1 - \text{loose all} = 1 - \prod_i (1-p_i)$. But, again, this is a special case that we make easier by observing the "trick". Without it, you'd get the same result by computing all $2^N-1$ outcomes' probabilities and summing them.